# Highlight the ComboBoxCellEditor choice on mousehover

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to achieve the ComboBox functionality in which the ComboBox values are highlighted on mouse hover. In ComboBoxCellEditor only the selected is highlighted when the drop down is shown. There is no effect of the mouse hover on the list.

[image]

In the above pic my cursor is pointing to String2 and its highlighting String2. Here i'm using ComboBox.

[image]

But In the above pic my cursor is pointing to String2 but its highlighting the String0 which is selected. I want to achieve the first pic functionality using ComboBoxCellEditor.

Comment: Do you want the drop-down of the Combo to open on mouse over?

Comment: No, i want to highlight the choice which is pointed by the mouse. It doesn't highlight the item on which i m pointing. It highlights the selected item in the ComboBoxCellEditor.

Comment: On Windows 7, the currently hovered item is highlighted. In doubt, clarify your question, add a screen shot, precisely describe actual vs. expected, tell which OS you are using. Note, however, that SWT, by design, uses the widgets of the underlying windowing system which controls their appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two implementations of a combo box in SWT:

- `Combo` uses the platform's native widget
- `CCombo` (C for custom) is a control composed of a text and a button which opens a `List` to let the user select an item

The `ComboBoxCellEditor` internally uses the `CCombo` widget. To have a combo box like shown in the first image of your question in a cell editor, you need to implement your own `AbstractComboBoxCellEditor` that uses the `Combo` widget.

The two combo box implementations are mostly API compatible. You may want to use a copy of the `ComboBoxCellEditor` as a start, change the type of the `comboBox` field to `Combo` and adjust the remaining code passages.